# How to modify the query when multiple columns are returned from inner query to resolve the error

Tags: sql-server

I have a complex query in which my inner query produces the correct result. But as my sub query returns more than on columns so i get the error "`Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the sub query is not introduced with EXISTS`"

How should i modify the query to resolve the error but i need the same number of columns of inner query.

**SQL Server 2012 Query**

```
select Distinct 
   s.SalesInvoiceID,
   cust.CustomerID,
   cust.Name,
   cust.FName,
   cust.CustomerCNIC,   

   CASE WHEN s.SpecialInsttPlan = 'No' 

   THEN 
        (s.TotalBill - s.Advance) / s.Installments
   ELSE
   (
        select Distinct Top 1 sip.Amount,iph.InsttNo
        from
        SpecialInsttPlan sip 
        join InstallmentPaymentHistory iph
        on iph.InsttNo=sip.InsttNo
        where
        sip.SalesInvoiceID=45 and iph.SalesInvoiceID=45 and 
        (iph.Status ='Pending' or iph.Status ='Up Coming') order by iph.InsttNo
    )

   END as Installment,
   s.TotalBill - s.Advance - sum(iph.Amount)   as BalanceAmount

from
   SalesInvoice s 
   inner join
      InstallmentPaymentHistory iph 
      on iph.SalesInvoiceID = s.SalesInvoiceID 
   inner join
      Customer cust 
      on s.CustomerID = cust.CustomerID 
where
   iph.SalesInvoiceID = 45
group by
   s.SalesInvoiceID,
   s.TotalBill,
   s.Installments,
   s.Discount,
   s.Advance,
   cust.Name,
   cust.FName,
   cust.CustomerID,
   cust.CustomerCNIC,
   s.SpecialInsttPlan,
   iph.InsttNo
```

Comment: What are you expecting here? Your subquery returns 2 columns, which one are you actually wanting to display? The error is telling you the problem here; a sub query can only return one column.

Comment: Are you trying to do a calculation from the sub query? What is the purpose of the sub query?

Comment: use this `select Distinct Top 1 (sip.Amount / iph.InsttNo) As Amount`, you do not need two column, you need to divide the values and do what you want to do.

Comment: @ Larnu In actual, from inner query i want to display  the column "sip.Amount" but due to  "order by iph.InsttNo" clause i am forced to use two coloumns in subquery

Comment: @ Hasan Mahmood  Division of two columns will produce the wrong result.

Comment: @ WEI_DBA , From inner query i only need the column of  "sip.Amount". But due to the need of "order by clause" i am forced to include "iph.InsttNo" as a second column in the inner query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.SalesInvoiceID,a.CustomerID,a.Name,a.FName,a.CustomerCNIC,

    CASE WHEN a.SpecialInsttPlan = 'No' 

    then 
        a.Installment
    else ( select sip.Amount from SpecialInsttPlan sip 
            where  a.Installment=sip.InsttNo and sip.SalesInvoiceID=44
          ) 
            end as Installment,a.BalanceAmount
from 

(
select Distinct
   s.SalesInvoiceID,
   cust.CustomerID,
   cust.Name,
   cust.FName,
   cust.CustomerCNIC,
   s.SpecialInsttPlan,

   CASE WHEN s.SpecialInsttPlan = 'No' 

   THEN 
        (s.TotalBill - s.Advance) / s.Installments 
   ELSE
   (
         select Distinct Top 1 iph.InsttNo
         from
            SpecialInsttPlan sip 
            join InstallmentPaymentHistory iph
            on iph.InsttNo=sip.InsttNo
         where
        sip.SalesInvoiceID=44 and iph.SalesInvoiceID=44 and 
        (iph.Status ='Pending' or iph.Status ='Up Coming')   order by iph.InsttNo


    )
   END as Installment, 
   s.TotalBill - s.Advance - sum(iph.Amount)   as BalanceAmount

from
   SalesInvoice s 
   inner join
      InstallmentPaymentHistory iph 
      on iph.SalesInvoiceID = s.SalesInvoiceID 
   inner join
      Customer cust 
      on s.CustomerID = cust.CustomerID 
where
   iph.SalesInvoiceID = 44
group by
   s.SalesInvoiceID,
   s.TotalBill,
   s.Installments,
   s.Discount,
   s.Advance,
   cust.Name,
   cust.FName,
   cust.CustomerID,
   cust.CustomerCNIC,
   s.SpecialInsttPlan) as a
```

As the inner can return only one column so i used another outer query and used only one column in inner query